# Refused: not authorized error occurs with IBM IoT Foundation on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

When I attempt to connect to the IBM IoT Foundation with a registered device, I receive the following error message:

> Error connecting to IBM IoT: {"errorCode":6,"errorMessage":"AMQJS0006E Bad Connack return code:5 Connection Refused: not authorized."}

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that you have expired as a member of your org if you created the service (and thereby the org) via the Bluemix dashboard.  When you log into Bluemix, you get a 24 hour pass as a guest.  You can then go into the IoTF dashboard and add yourself as a permanent member.

Do this by launching the IoTF dashboard from your Bluemix IoT service and then go to the Access tab.  You should see yourself as a "guest" user, and you can add yourself as a permanent member.  From the Access tab, add yourself as a permanent member of the org. 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, maybe just API attempts for trial are out?
CHeck in Bluemix panel